# For Loop To Get One Variable From Each Nested Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, nested

I am trying to go through some Json and just get the "city_name" value from each nested array and print it in a list. QUESTION: How do you loop over an array and just get the first element from each array?

```
“state”: [
    {
      “city_name”: “Denver”,
      “timezone”: “MST”,
    },
    {
      “city_name”: “Austin”,
      “timezone”: “CST”,
    }
{
      “city_name”: “Atlanta”,
      “timezone”: “EST”,
    }
  ],
```

Javascript that I tried:

```
fetch(‘URL’).then(function(response) { 
        return response.json();
    }).then(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        for (x in data.state) {
        document.getElementById("cities").innerHTML += data.state.city_name + "<br>";
    }    
    });
```

Response:
undefined
undefined
undefined

Is this the correct way to get the value inside the array? Why does it say undefined? 
*this is just sample data to help explain my problem

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-a-bad-idea

Comment: `const cityList = data.State.map(element => element.city_name);`

Comment: Because you don't have a property named `"state"`. It's `"State"` and it's an array so you should use `for ... of` instead of `for ... in`.

Comment: Pavlo: I tried the const cityList = data.State.map(element => element.city_name); But this just repeated Denver 3 times. I placed it inside the For Loop and outside.

Comment: Derek: The capital State was a typo in my sample, I've corrected it. I tried changing it to For "of" but that still resulted in "undefined"

Comment: It says undefined because the property `state` is an array, and the array itself doesn't have a property called `city_name` (so, `data.state.city_name` is wrong).  You have to iterate the array and retrieve each element which *does* have a property called city_name (so, `data.state[x].city_name` depending on how you iterate it, don't use for..in).  The answer and comment that use `map` are both appropriate and both would work.  If they don't work then your data is not what you have posted above.

Answer (score 1):

```
fetch(‘URL’).then(function(response) { 
  return response.json();
}).then(function(data) {
  let cities = data.state.map(e => e.city_name);
  document.getElementById("cities").innerHTML += cities.join('<br/>');
});
```

This should work assuming `data` is an object containing a property `state`